# How does pipe to "while read" work?

Tags: pipe, sh

As I understand it, in the command

```
$ echo "a b\nc d" | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

the `while` command receives only one line at a time so its body is only executed once per line. My question is therefor: What is the purpose of `while` in this context and why does

```
$ echo "a b\nc d" | { read line; echo "$line"; }
```

only output the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these commands

```
echo 'a b\nc d' | {

  # this command is going to read until the first newline, so we get
  # line='a b'
  read line
  echo "$line"

  # this command continues on, so we get
  # line='c d'
  read line
  echo "$line"
}
```

Comment: I'm using POSIX Shell (sh), not Bash. The command with `while` works as expected.

Comment: As I understand pipes the read command should be executed twice: First "a b" is piped to `read` and then "c d" is piped to `read`.

Comment: Please, tell me what I get wrong in the following interpretation of your command with two `read`s: 1. The first line "a b" is transfered through the pipe. The first `read` command consumes it but the second `read` command has no input. 2. The second line "c d" is transfered through the pipe. The first `read` command consumes it but the second `read` command has no input.

Comment: OK, now I think I understand. When you pipe to a command *f* I have always thought that *f* gets executed once per line but that's not correct; It waits for input until end of file is reached.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom it would only do that if you used a loop

Answer (score 2):

The `while` command (yes, loops are considered a type of command in shell, not just a syntactic construct) receives the entire input. The `read` command inherits its standard input from the `while`, and it is `read` that consumes a single line from that input.

The purpose of the `while` command is to ensure that each time `read` succeeds, the body of the loop is educated and that `read` is executed again. Once `read` has a non-zero exit status, the `while` command itself exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I somewhat foolishly assumed that a command receiving input from a pipe be executed once per input line.

Comment: An understandable mistake, given that many programs do operate on each line of the input (`awk`, `sed`, `cut`, etc.), so that there is an implicit loop.